# "sed/awk" value assignment in bash scripting

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have a file "IP"  with number of blocked  different subnet IP addresses, I want to change  last octal digits of subnet, like `1.1.1.5` to `1.1.1.0/24`. I wrote script. Issue is that `awk` command out doesn't assigned to any variable.

Example:

```
sed  "s/139.196.8.79/139.196.8.0\/24/g" ip |a=$(awk -F. '{print $4}')
```

But when I run `awk -F. '{print S4}'`, it returns output but doesn't assign value to variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your sample input with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your expected output but... looking your example here above, maybe, you're looking for something like this:

```
$ a=$(sed "s/139.196.8.79/139.196.8.0\/24/g" ip | awk -F. '{print $4}')
$ echo $a
0/24
```

Comment: That would transform a random digit string like `6213951962837926` into `62139.196.8.0/2426`. You have to escape the `.`s.

Comment: Thanks..yeah tha's what I was expecting..but i want to use "for loop" in this script and want get each ip address  from "IP" file and use it as pattern and gets break it's octactes using awk and finally replacing last octate with subnet 0./24.  Thanks for all prompt response

Comment: @EchoQ sounds like you are approaching this the wrong way and planning to call various tools multiple times inside a shell loop. Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 and the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

WHat you were trying to write is:

```
a="$(sed  "s/139.196.8.79/139.196.8.0\/24/g" ip | awk -F. '{print $4}' )"
```

but you need to escape the RE metacharacters (`.`s) and you don't need sed when you're using awk:

```
a="$(awk -F. '{gsub(/139\.196\.8\.79/,"139.196.8.0/24"); print $4}' ip)"
```

The above is untested and may be wrong or not the best approach since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output in your question.

Note that the above should really be using word boundaries if an IP addr like `139.196.8.790` can occur in your data but again without sample input and expected output....

Answer (score 0):

A pipe creates a sub process. This means that you create the variable in a sub shell, which gets discarded right after. In order to access the variable, you have to group your commands into curly braces:

```
sed  "s/139.196.8.79/139.196.8.0\/24/g" ip | {
    a=$(awk -F. '{print $4}')
    echo $a
}
```

Everything you want to do with `a` must be done in the sub shell, in which `a` has been defined.

Comment: I will test your all suggestions and will update.thanks for everyone